# Implement configurable date format in spring mvc and jquery

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, datepicker

I want to give an option to configure date-format for the application in properties file.
I had thought of implementing it using conversion service in spring and a model which I will use as date format property for jquery datepicker. As I went a little further I found out that SimpleDateFormat and jquery datepicker formats the date in different pattern for the same format string. There should have been a standard for this but unfortunately that is not the case.
What is the other way to do this?

Comment: I cant believe nobody is trying this.

Comment: look at jodatime, and lots of people are using configurable properties with spring.

Comment: could you suggest a demo for the same please.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a few reads to fully grasp what the problem was, but it sounds like you know how to do the formatting with Spring but are having issues with the fact that jquery uses different patterns than Java when formatting a Date? I believe your best recourse may be to simply store two patterns in your properties:

```
java.date.format=yyyy-MM-dd...
jquery.date.format=yyyy-mm-dd...
```

Obviously that means configuration would require making sure you used the equivalent format for each property so that they were always converted properly, but the only alternative I can see is creating an automatic format converter from jquery to java (or vice versa.)

Alternatively, have you considered simply converting the date to milliseconds before submitting and then using that to recreate the Date on the java end? Would be much simpler, I imagine.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

Sounds like the goal is ultimately to have a single configurable property:

```
date.format=yyyy-mm-dd...
```

In order to avoid a complex mapping from jquery's date formatting tokens to Java's date formatting tokens, it might be best to simply create your own custom date format in the form of:

```
[millis],[timeZoneOffset]
```

Your properties file should contain the jquery format string so that your Datepicker will render the format you wish the client to see. Then, when a date is picked, you should convert it to your `[millis],[timeZoneOffset]` custom format before submitting to your controller. On the Spring/Java side, you should create and register a custom `Date` converter that accepts this `[millis],[timeZoneOffset]` format and creates the corresponding `Date` object.

Personally, I don't see anything wrong with creating your own custom date format to solve this problem. You are going to save yourself a lot of headache that would come from trying to map jquery to Java, and, ultimately, it's what Spring's custom converters are there to help with.

Comment: I like your second solution, is there any setting in datepicker that will allow me to display dates in the date format I want and give the value in milliseconds?

Comment: I realized that there will be a problem if I take datepicket input as milliseconds. Generally client and server have different time zones and it will be impossible to handle different timezones in this case.

Comment: Hmm good point. What if you used a custom converter that took a String like "[millis],[timeZoneOffset]" and converted that to a `Date` object in Java? That way, you could always use the jquery format string in your properties file, as the client is where the user will visibly see the date, and achieve the proper conversion without a need to map jquery's format to Java's.

Comment: I appreciate the solution you are trying to give, but I am sure even you will agree that this is a good solution. I am sorry I cant take this. I think this is common scenario and there is a better solution for this.

Comment: I think you meant "not" a good solution. I'm not sure why. All you would be doing is creating your own custom date format. How is "[millis],[timeZoneOffset]" any less valid a custom Date format than "yyyy-mm-dd...?" The problem here is you are dealing with a non-standard situation, so you need a non-standard solution. Ultimately, if you want a single format in your properties file, you will HAVE to perform your own conversion between jquery and Java date formats. However you choose to do that format conversion is up to you. Gonna edit my answer to recommend a simple custom date format.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong as far as on the java side, but in my app there will be a lot of datepickers particularly for filtering data and used with ajax. I can go ahead to use this if I can find a solution to do this in my jquery avoiding boilerplate code. I will still look into your solution. Its just jquery I am concerned about,  I will take this as soon as I find a way to handle it. Thanks. I really appretiate your effort.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with jquery's Datepicker, but generally you should be able to extend anything in javascript so that you can always rely on the value being fetched to be in the format you desire. Write the conversion from their format to yours, and then use your extended component instead of the stock Datepicker, and boom, you're done. =) Good luck!